# Connectionstring issue. c# sql express 2012.

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

Here is my connection string.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbo.Employee; User Id=user1; Password=Password11";
```

I have a database called `Employee` with a table called `[EVUSERS]` in the `dbo` schema.

I have created a database login under sql logins for this username and password, for some reason it wont allow me to login to the server at the connect to server window.

Whenever I try and use the connection string in the form in my C# I keep getting an error

`logon failed for 'user1'`

I am not sure if its a server side issue I have or a c# side. thanks

Comment: seems like wrong password. can you verify the password ?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to that database with that user/password combination using SSMS?

Comment: I don't think you need the `dbo.` in front of your Database name.  But yes it seems like a username/password issue.

Comment: Is your password `Password11"` including the `"`?

Comment: Hi. The password I have set in SQL express is (without the quotes) "Password11" I am unable to connect to the database in express using this login after I have created the user.

Comment: as TTeeple said. Try SSMS. if you still cant log in, and you get the same error messasge, then your password is wrong.

Comment: I believe @EvanL is correct. You don't need `dbo.` in front of your database.  The schema relates to your database objects, not the database itself.

Comment: When I try to login to express. I made sure the password was correct and the username. I get error "Login failed for user .(microsoft sql server error 18456)

Comment: That is sql server authentication

Comment: BTW it is with mgmt studio

Comment: @EPOColla, sounds like you created the user but did not enable CONNECT access to the database.  Refer to the answer with the article below on how to create a login and grant access.

Comment: The connect access is Granted in the login properties - permission to connect to database engine. So I do not know any other way which I do not have access to the database.

Comment: Try another user, maybe 'sa'. If that works then its definitely the permission for your user.

Comment: login for sa has failed aswell. i changed my connectionstring to @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Employee; User Id=sa; There is no password is there?

Comment: The sa password is whatever you made it when you installed that particular instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "login failed" error generally means one of few things:

1. The login doesn't even exist. See the ["Create a Login"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) article on MSDN.
2. The login doesn't have access to the database, which is also covered in that article.
3. The password is wrong.